# why springboot clear the old log configuration when starts up

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

There is a legacy application which uses JUL and registers handlers via code. Now I use springboot within the legacy app.

I tried with minimum spring boot dependency which only includes spring-boot-starter and excludes spring-boot-starter-logging; set org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem to none in application.properties; use either commons-logging or jcl-over-slf4j. And JUL configuration is always cleared when spring boot starts up.

Is there a way to keep JUL configuration no change when spring boot starts up?

The spring boot version is 1.5.20 due to the legacy app is compiled with java7

Comment: Define "cleared".

Comment: all properties defined in logging.properties are lost; all handlers registered via code are lost.  with LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("").getHandlers() can see the difference before/after spring boot starts up

Answer (score 0):

[this link partially answers the question](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8933)

However, still not sure the mechanism of Logger initialization of Spring Boot